# How to solve the ODE for population growth

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

$$\frac{dN}{dt} = bN^2 - dN , \quad\ N(0) = N_0$$

I am trying to find the solution to this for hours, but I just can't get it to work. For the seperation of variables, I keep getting

$$\int\frac{-1}{dN}.dN + \int\frac{b}{bdN-d^2}.dN = \int dt $$.

But past that I can't factor out N to produce a final equation as a solution: N(t) = ....

Some help would be greatly appreciated :)

edit: Regarding a solution, I end up with:

$$-ln(dN) + ln(dbN-d^2)^b=t+c $$

Comment: perhaps the solution is expected to be in implicit form. You didn't write a solution in any form yet, as you didn't evaluate the integrals. Both integrals on the left side involve $\ln$. For example $\int\frac 1{x-a}=\ln|x-a|+$const.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I just added my last line of working before I get rather stuck trying to separate N.

Comment: wouldn't it be $-ln(dN) + ln(dbN-d^2)^{\frac1d}=t+c$? Note $\int\frac 1{qx-a}=\frac1q\ln|qx-a|+$const, using a substitution $u=qx-a, du=qdx, dx=\frac1q du$.

Comment: Correction noted, thank you for the explanation. But where do I go from here in order to obtain a final solution? As far as I see, $$ln(dbN - d^2)^\frac{1}{d}$$ will still prevent me from separating N from the equation?

Comment: Polynomial in $N$ invites to do logarithmic substitution as we know logarithmic derivative as well as logarithm laws of exponents.

Comment: The $-\ln(dN)$ doesn't seem right either. Formally you need to make a substitution, $u=dN$, etc, or what is easier just rewrite $\int\frac{-1}{dN}dN$ as $-\frac1d\int\frac1N dN=-\frac1d\ln|N|$, and proceed from there, and simplify and solve for $N$. But before I noticed what you did, I posted my solution, simplifying the integrals first to make it easy to take antiderivatives, without using substitutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $d$ is a constant, the letter $d$ is perhaps not the best choice, as one tends to confuse $dN$ (i.e. $d$ times $N$) with $\frac{dN}{dt}$ (derivative of $N$ with respect to $t$).

$\frac{dN}{dt} = bN^2 - dN , \quad\ N(0) = N_0$

Apart from that, I seem to get a different equation when I separate variables.
(Or, rather, I simplify in a different way.)

$\frac{dN}{bN^2 - dN} = dt$, thus $\int\frac{dN}{bN^2 - dN}=\int dt$,
and from here 
$-\frac1d\int\frac{dN}N +\frac bd\int\frac{dN}{bN - d}=\int dt$ and
$-\frac1d\int\frac{dN}N +\frac 1d\int\frac{dN}{N - \frac db}=\int dt$, so
$-\int\frac{dN}N +\int\frac{dN}{N - \frac db}=d\int dt$.
We get $-\ln|N|+\ln|N - \frac db|=dt+C$, hence
$\ln|\frac{N - \frac db}N|=dt+C$, and
$|\frac{N - \frac db}N|=e^{dt+C}=e^{dt}e^C$, giving us
$\frac{N - \frac db}N=e^{dt}K$, where $K=\pm e^C$.
The latter is easy to solve for $N$ algebraically.
$N - \frac db=Ne^{dt}K$, and
$N -Ne^{dt}K= \frac db$, so $N(1 -e^{dt}K)= \frac db$, thus
$N= \frac d{b(1 -e^{dt}K)}$, general solution.

When $t=0$ we get $N_0= \frac d{b(1-K)}$, thus
$1-K= \frac d{bN_0}$, so $K=1-\frac d{bN_0}$.

Edit. Answering a follow up question in the comment below, this solution may become unbounded at a finite time, say time $T$. This could happen if the denominator becomes $0$ for $t=T$, that is $1-e^{dT}K=0$. Solving for $T$ we get $\frac1K=e^{dT}$ so $\ln(\frac1K)=-\ln(K)=dT$, and $T=\frac{-\ln(K)}d=\frac{\ln(\frac1K)}d$. Since we want $T>0$, the latter quantity may be positive either when (a) $0<K<1$ and $d>0$, or when (b) $K>1$ and $d<0$. (I don't know the context to try to determine which of the two options (a) or (b) might be more feasible than the other, perhaps (a), if $d$ is not supposed to be negative, but perhaps each of (a) and (b) is valid.)

Formally, I am supposed to write the answer without using $K$ (though it is oK), but in terms of the original parameters $b,d,N_0$.

Since $K=1-\frac d{bN_0}=\frac{bN_0-d}{bN_0}$, we obtain
$N=N(t)=\frac d{b(1 -e^{dt}\frac{bN_0-d}{bN_0})}= 
\frac{dN_0}{bN_0 -e^{dt}(bN_0-d)}=\frac{dN_0}{bN_0(1-e^{dt})+de^{dt}}$.

Then there may be some finite time $T$ (i.e. $0<T<\infty$) such that $\lim_{t\to T^-}N(t)=\infty$, this would happen when the denominator equals $0$, i.e. 
$bN_0 -e^{dT}(bN_0-d)=0$. This was already solved (but in terms of $K$), so again, $e^{dT}=\frac1K=\frac{bN_0}{bN_0-d}$, and $T=(\ln\frac{bN_0}{bN_0-d})/d=-(\ln\frac{bN_0-d}{bN_0})/d$ (whichever expression is more appropriate to work with).

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes perfect sense and I followed a very similar process up to the point where I failed to factorise with ln terms enough. The only problem I have with this is that the follow up question is as follows:

Show that the solution to this model might become unbounded at a finite time, t∗, by finding an expression in terms of N0, b and d for a finite time, t∗, for which N(t∗) is
unbounded (infinite).

Does this mean N(t) is supposed to rise to infinity as t approaches infinity? Is the aforementioned solution still correct in light of this information?

Comment: Show that the solution to this model might become unbounded at a finite time, t∗, by finding an expression in terms of N0, b and d for a finite time, t∗, for which N(t∗) is unbounded (infinite).

Comment: You are very welcome! I edited my answer to address the follow up question. (Formally, we would have $\lim_{t\to T^-}N(t)=\infty$.)

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems so simple following your explanations and I'll try to follow the steps with the rest of the questions. In my instance, d > 0 so solution (a) is perfect for me, but the explanation for both solutions was very valuable. Thanks again, that was awesome! :)

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer, Welcome to MSE, good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Re-write the ODE as $$N^{-2}\frac{dN}{dt}+\frac{d}{N}=b.$$
Let $y=1/N$, then we get
$$-\frac{dy}{dt}+dy=b$$, the integrating factor id $I=e^{dt}$. Next the solution of
ODE is $$y=e^{-dt}\int b e^{dt} dt+C e^{=dt}= \frac{b}{d}+C e^{-dt} \Rightarrow N^2=\frac{1}{b/d+Ce^{-dt}},$$ where $$C=\frac{1}{N_0^2}-\frac{b}{d}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! So the values to sub in are as follows: t = 5 years, b = 0.001, d = 0.5, N0 = 450. Following your formula, I get N(5) = 545. The only problem I have here is that your formula ends with N^2 = ... Does that mean I have to sqrt the RHS for N(t) = ...? Because doing so gives me answers which are totally incorrect?

Comment: @narutorulez Oh I am really sorry these are not not $N^2, N_0^2$ actually these should be $N, N_0$ I ave edited thse typos. Please see. Thanks